# VS Code: Configure keyboard shortcuts to move cursors when !textInputFocus

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I'd like to use Ctrl+B/Ctrl+F for VSCode Neovim when editing code, which I assume `textInputFocus` is about, and use them to move the cursor left/right when not editing code, for example in:

- Command Palette
- Search Files
- Code Search
- Settings UI

VSCode Neovim doesn't interact with those text fields, so you can't use h/l to move your cursor left/right, which is why I want Ctrl+B/Ctrl+F there.

I tried the following keybindings.json, but it didn't work:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+b",
        "command": "cursorLeft",
        "when": "!textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+f",
        "command": "cursorRight",
        "when": "!textInputFocus"
    }
]
```

Note: The same thing seems to work on macOS without any configuration. I'd like to have the same behavior on Linux. A key remapper is not useful for it because it can't be aware of VSCode NeoVim's current mode.

Comment: You should explain exactly what you are trying to do, if the editor does not have focus you can't see the cursor anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I agree that it wasn't clear. I updated my question.